# Is there a way to import repository from zip to jfrog artifactory using API?

Tags: rest, artifactory

I want to import repository from zip to jFrog Artifactory server using command line and API only without the UI.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Import Repository Content` from the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/rtf6x/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ImportRepositoryContent) on repository import should be helpful here.

> Description: Import one or more repositories.
> Since: 2.2.2
> Security: Requires a valid admin user
> Usage: POST: /api/import/repositories
> Requests Params:
>
> - path - The file system path to import from. This may point to a specific folder to import data for a single repository, or to the parent "repositories" folder to import data for all repositories.
> - repo - Empty/null repo -> all
> - metadata - Include metadata - default 1
> - verbose - Verbose - default 0
>
> Produces: text/plain
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> POST: /api/import/repositories?path=pathToRepos&verbose=1
> ```

Comment: It is! but I don't see an option for importing zip file like I have in the UI.. only this version: `POST: /api/import/repositories?path=pathToRepos&verbose=1` that says _"This may point to a specific folder to import data for a single repository"_

Comment: Use this 'curl -u<admin>:<password> -XPOST http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/import/repositories?path=<The_file_system_path_to_import_from>&repo=<Repo_key_name_to_which_import_needs_to_be_performed&verbose=1' curl command to perform the import. Zip file will consists of all repositories so if you need to include all the repositories then pass on the system path of the zip under "Path" parameter without passing anything in "repo" parameter